# Installing Ubuntu 19.10 on ONLY a USB from a Live, persistent USB made in Windows 10 using Rufus

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, live-usb

this is my first post, I feel like this is an issue nobody else has had before but I'm probably wrong.

I created a persistent live bootable USB from windows using Rufus 3.9. 
I want to install chrome as well as firefox and use apt-get update and apt-get upgrade while keeping the USB persistent. 
I think this is only possible if I do a complete install of Ubuntu, but I want to keep all of my files on the computer and only install Ubuntu on the USB drive. 
The USB is 16 GB and I made my persistent storage 8 GB in Rufus. Rufus makes 2 partitions, one for the EFI boot (I think) and the other is a casper-rw.
If you're going to point me to a link, please direct me where to look as I have done some of my own research and nothing seems to address my specific case. I hope I'm wrong, but I've tried and nothing seems to look or be the way that my machine is. 
[1](https://www.fosslinux.com/10212/how-to-install-a-complete-ubuntu-on-a-usb-flash-drive.htm)  [2](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/install-ubuntu-mate-using-something-else-method/651) [3](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Preparing_to_Install_Ubuntu_alongside_Windows) [4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) [5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849288/persistent-live-usb-limitations) [6](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/index.html) [7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator). 
When I run the "Install Ubuntu 19.10" thing on the desktop, there is no "Try Ubuntu" option. I get through the options and then go to the partitions window and that's where I have trouble. My computer is unable to connect to wifi because I think that is an extra feature that comes with the install, so my apt-get requests fail. I want to make sure that none of my computer's files are erased, so I took out the storage from the computer. 
I tried to unmount the persistent storage using GPartEd, and doing this allowed me to make a new partition table in the last section of the installer GUI, although any changes I made were deleted since there is no longer any persistence. Then I tried installing and got an endless supply of SQUASHFS errors.
I am trying to install on a 2010 macbook pro that basically can't be moved when it is powered on, I'm not sure of the cause.

This is for a homework assignment, and I have limited experience in Linux. I've essentially taken an intro to linux course, but other than that I have no real experience with the OS. The teacher says he has a solution key, so if I can't figure this out, I'll update my post with his answer.

Comment: This is an easy homework. Just search for "ubuntu persistent rufus". There are howtos with pictures and explanations. I hope you can find them. Good luck.

Comment: Squashfs errors mean faulty install media, or you removed/unmounted it creating the error yourself, either way `squashfs` mean your 'live' media is flawed, and you need to return to the validation of ISO stage, or the write to install media (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any media used, be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/compact-flash/..)

Answer (score 0):

### Making a Full install of Ubuntu to USB from a Live install

You can use Ubuntu running in RAM to make a Full install to the USB drive it was booted from, (16GB minimum), or to a second USB.

Boot the USB drive using the toram option, that is, at boot press shift, if it is a SDC or Rufus install, if It is a UNetbootin install, press tab at the boot menu. Press F6, type a space then 'toram'.

The Live USB should be booted in the same BIOS or UEFI mode as the internal drive is.

I prefer going to GParted or Disks to unmount the usb drive partition so I can see what is happening. Unmount it using your preference.

Start Install Ubuntu, at "Installation type" select 'Something else'.

Under 'Device for boot loader installation' select the target drive.

Create a new partition table on the target drive.

Click the plus sign to create a "/" partition.

Complete install and you should have a Full install USB that works on your machine. Run 'sudo update-grub' to add your internal HDD to the USB's boot menu.

For a step by step guide to doing a Full install of Ubuntu on USB see: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 19.10 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step/1217839#1217839)

Comment: I tried. Here are my issues. When I turn my macbook on, I hold the "option" key to select the drive I want to boot to. I select "EFI partition" with a USB symbol. I can't load into the Grub menu, holding shift doesn't work, pressing escape seems to [freeze my computer](https://www.imgur.com/gallery/n2dKTqc). I can't change my grub options because I get "Failed to get canonical path of /cow." I can't change the mount path of my boot drive (sda1) because it is already mounted to /cdrom which is why I would need to boot 'toram' correct? @C.S.Cameron